# Avoiding nested models in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

If I have data that is best modelled as an n-ary tree where each node node may have up to n child nodes. In Backbone.js I am tempted to define a model called Node, that contains a collection of Nodes.

```
Node = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        children: undefined
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.set({
                children: new NodeList()
            });
    }
});

NodeList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Node
});
```

There are (at least) two problems with this:

1. I have read that a Backbone.js Model should not contain any
   attributes that are not valid JSON types, and a Backbone.js is not a valid JSON type.
2. If I wanted a child Node
   to maintain a reference to it's parent Node, I end up with a cyclic
   relationship that causes Backbone.js to crash when calling toJSON.

How should I solve this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [backbone-relational](http://backbonerelational.org/)

Comment: I'll have a look at that, thank you. But I'm concerned that I'm trying to do something I shouldn't. Is the problem I'm facing better solved without changing libraries? Should I change my approach instead?

Comment: I think your approach is fine. In addition to backbone relational, have a look at [marionette's composite view](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md#recursive-by-default).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a look at [Backbone Associations](http://dhruvaray.github.io/backbone-associations/).
I have used it and I had faced the same cyclic JSON conversion issue. I raised it to the Author and they have fixed it in their latest release. Hope this helps.